# Sitecore Scheduled Job: Unable to run

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am very new with Sitecore, I am trying to create one task, but after creating task I configured command and task at content editor. Still I don't see run now option for my task at content editor. Need help.I want to know where the logs of scheduled jobs are written?

Comment: It should be in the same Sitecore logs folder, to be able to help provide more info like code, the schedule field value in your task and any extra info you can provide.

Comment: Can you please provide more information such as screenshot and code snippets. The question is not clear

Comment: I created one task using VS solution(.cs) and configured the command and schedule using Content Editor.I don't get run now option for my task at content editor and it's not getting run by sitecore.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 places where you can define custom task.

1. In database
2. In config file

If you decide to go with 1st option

- a task item must be created under `/sitecore/system/tasks/schedules`
  item in the “core” database (default behavior).
- no matter what schedule you set on that item, it may never be executed, if you do not have right `DatabaseAgent` looking after that task item.
- DatabaseAgent periodically checks task items and if tasks must be
  executed (based on the value set in the Scheduling field), it
  executes actual code
- By default the `DatabaseAgent` is called each 10
  minutes

If you decide to go with 2nd option, check [this](https://sdn.sitecore.net/articles/administration/database%20maintenance.aspx) article first.

In short, you need to define your task class and start method in the config files (check out the /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx page, to make sure config changes are applied successfully)

```
<scheduling>
<!--
 Time between checking for scheduled tasks waiting to execute 
-->
<frequency>00:00:05</frequency>    
<agent type="NameSpace.TaskClass" method="MethodName" interval="00:10:00"/>
</agent>   
</scheduling>
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the other answers, you can use config file or database to execute your task. However, it seems that you want to run it manually.

I have a custom module on the Sitecore Marketplace which allows you to select the task you want run. Here is the [link](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_Run_Agent.aspx?sc_lang=en)

In brief, you need to go to the Sitecore control panel, then click on administration and lastly click on the Run Agent.

It will open a window where you can select the task. I am assuming that the task you have implemented does not take the Item details on which you are when triggering the job.